# Max difference between arrays

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic-programming

I have a coding issue.

Suppose that you have two arrays with equal length.

```
Arr1 = [1,3,8,4] --> Boxes arriving to a storage room
Arr2 = [3,9,1,5] --> Boxees up for leaving a storage room
```

Each index(not the value saved in the index) corresponds to a specific month.
You want to find the best combination of boxes leaving resulting in maximum boxes send to stores.
So for the above

```
Max diff => (3-1)+(9-3)+(5-8) => 10
```

You could do a brute-force approach, but that would result in a O(n^2) run time.
I've looked into doing a divide & Conquerer approach however I don't really know to start.

**Notice**: I'm not interested in a copy of code. I whish to optain a method for aproaching this problem which will lead to me developing the code myself.

Comment: Not able to get your question can you add some more example ? And its 11 after summing up ?

Comment: it is 5 after summing up `(3-1)+(9-3)+(5-8) = 5`

Comment: Why `5 - 8` instead of `5 - 4`?

Comment: @Reza I think he is asking about absolute value but still not able to get the question